# allocate users from activity frequency by tiers using Pig on Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Need to count the # of users in each group, and group allocation for each user is based on their payment they made (e.g. either payment less than 2, or between 3 and 5, or more than 5). Here is my current code, wondering if any ways to make it more elegant? Is it possible to complete the logic by one group by statement? Thanks.

```
customer_group = group payments_feed by customerID;
customer_payment_count=foreach customer_group generate customerID, COUNT(payments_feed) as payment_amount;
tier1 = filter customer_payment_count by payment_amount <= 2;
tier2 = filter customer_payment_count by 3 <= payment_amount <= 5;
tier3 = filter customer_payment_count by payment_amount > 5;
tier1_group = group tier1 by all;
tier1_count = foreach tier1_group generate COUNT_STAR(tier1);
tier2_group = group tier2 by all;
tier2_count = foreach tier2_group generate COUNT_STAR(tier2);
tier3_group = group tier3 by all;
tier3_count = foreach tier3_group generate COUNT_STAR(tier3);
result = UNION tier1_count, tier2_count, tier3_count;
```

Some dummy data, schema customer ID (unique), payment (value always 1 since it represent times of payments customer made),

```
1 1
2 1
1 1
3 1
4 1
1 1
2 1
1 1
1 1
5 1
```

In this case, customer 1 has made 5 payments, which should be tier 2, and all other customers made payments not more than 2 times, they all belong to tier 1.

So, expected output is,

```
4 1 0
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: Give us some dummy data.?

Comment: @AnkurSingh, sure, add some data. And your advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: you give your dummy data .. Can you give what you want in output ?

Comment: @AnkurSingh, sure, update with expected output. :)

Comment: I think we use the "Group" this no of time. But we can optimize your 3 line of filter into 1 line . Other wise code is optimized.

Comment: @AnkurSingh, how do you optimize into one line? Appreciate for your sample code. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The no. of **GROUP** is sufficient for calculating the same. Because for counting the no of tuple in a particular bag there is a extra **GROUP** is used. But instead of using three **FILTER**. You can use **SPLIT** and The Code looks like :

```
customer_group = group payments_feed by customerID;
customer_payment_count=foreach customer_group generate customerID, COUNT(payments_feed) as payment_amount;
split into customer_payment_count into tier1 if(coun<=2), tier2 if(coun>=3 AND coun<=5),tier3 if(coun>5);
tier1_group = group tier1 by all;
tier1_count = foreach tier1_group generate COUNT_STAR(tier1);
tier2_group = group tier2 by all;
tier2_count = foreach tier2_group generate COUNT_STAR(tier2);
tier3_group = group tier3 by all;
tier3_count = foreach tier3_group generate COUNT_STAR(tier3);
result = UNION tier1_count, tier2_count, tier3_count;
```

Comment: Thanks Ankur, what do you mean "no. of GROUP"? Number of group? Or?

Comment: yes its number of GROUP keyword you used in the code

Comment: Hi Ankur, thanks for the comments. I see you also use 3 group-by to calculate count for each tier, any ideas to make more elegant? Like using one group by or? :)

Comment: As my knowledge it is used because for calculating the no of tuple we must have to group by All then we calculate the COUNT . But it may be optimize by UDF. And I am not perfect in UDF

Comment: Thanks Ankur for the details. Could you highlight comparing my code, what are improvements from your implementation? :)

Comment: Thanks for all the help, Ankur. Mark your reply as answer. :)